# Hot code is not working in Maven project using Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, debugging, deployment

My EAR is deployed in JBoss 1.7 and it's a Maven project. I export this Maven project as Java project. Hot code is not working for me. I tried the below points:

1. Enabled build automatically
2. Disable "Abort build when build path error occur"
3. Removed unwanted projects from project tab

Comment: What do u mean by Hot code?

Comment: More details about what you are trying to achieve would be welcomed.

Comment: Hot code replace (HCR) is a debugging technique whereby the Eclipse Java debugger transmits new class files over the debugging channel to another JV .